# Uninstall Vestacp Ubuntu 1.04

Tags: ubuntu, vesta

I need your help. Install vesta control panel, and I stopped working the localhost web and phpmyadmin. Then uninstall Vesta, but it still does not work. I do not know if I deleted it correctly, or what, please, I need help with this, I'm new configuring a server. So far everything was well installed what is LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Vesta fully is a big procedure, you need to see every dependency that has been installed for it.

So small solution reinstall a clean copy of ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

LAWD JEEEBUS!!!

Before you do anything do yourself a huge favor and install synaptic:

```
sudo apt install synaptic -y
```

I pray you did not run that apt remove. You'd be removing some pretty essential apps, like sudo, and apt...

```
apt-get remove apache2-suexec-custom libapache2-mod-ruid2 libapache2-mod-rpaf libapache2-mod-fcgid libapache2-mod-php php php-common php-cgi php-mysql php-curl php-fpm php-pgsql awstats webalizer vsftpd proftpd-basic bind9 **exim4** exim4-daemon-heavy clamav-daemon spamassassin dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d roundcube-core roundcube-mysql roundcube-plugins mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client postgresql postgresql-contrib phppgadmin phpmyadmin mc flex **whois** rssh **git** idn **zip sudo** bc ftp lsof **ntpdate** rrdtool **quota e2fslibs** bsdutils **e2fsprogs** **curl** imagemagick fail2ban dnsutils bsdmainutils **cron** vesta vesta-nginx vesta-php expect vim-common vesta-ioncube vesta-softaculous apparmor-utils
```

This is better, but still dangerous, very dangerous.

```
sudo apt remove apache2-suexec-custom libapache2-mod-ruid2 libapache2-mod-rpaf libapache2-mod-fcgid libapache2-mod-php php php-common php-cgi php-mysql php-curl php-fpm php-pgsql awstats webalizer vsftpd proftpd-basic bind9 exim4 exim4-daemon-heavy clamav-daemon spamassassin dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d roundcube-core roundcube-mysql roundcube-plugins postgresql postgresql-contrib phppgadmin phpmyadmin mc flex idn bc ftp lsof rrdtool imagemagick fail2ban bsdmainutils vesta vesta-nginx vesta-php expect vim-common vesta-ioncube vesta-softaculous apparmor-utils
```

Try that one, also may wanna run a reinstall of your flavor desktop/server

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop -y
```

Remember synaptic? Well that guy has a nice "broken" section you can check out and determine if your system is hosed or not. Might be worth a look!

Comment: These commands don't make a lot of sense. Could you explain a bit the reasoning behind remving `cron`, `apparmor`, etc... ?

Comment: SURE! 

Good question btw, honestly. Get used to the "man" of every damn command in linux... There's those among us that are sticklers for that kind of crap.

    man {program}

Take the time and look up something simple as "sudo" and you'll see the true purpose and power of the command. The command and options are what makes Linux far superior than M$ on any given day.

Comment: ***ONTO YOUR QUESTION.*** 

cron is a task scheduler. Plain and simple. You can automate ANY TASK at ANY given specified time/sequence/occurrence. For example, you can have a simple email alert from postfix sent to your gmail account everytime a ping response dies from 8.8.8.8 only on Mondays. Or in the example below, when to run a veeam backup!

    0 6 * * * veeamconfig job start --id {9453379c-0482-409a-b16b-eece09515be9} --retriable --scheduled --highpriority

Comment: Don't get disheartened by not knowing ***EVERYTHING*** right now. If you get confused come on back, read up first though. Hell, wait until you're really going to have fun with psad/fwsnort/iptables on a LAMP server. The pain. The horror. My iptables is a 13 MB file, it spans almost 200 pages and it's only text. LOTS of research for that to really work.

Comment: [Screenshot of datum from my iptables.conf][1]

My point is GUI is nice, but it's a tool for efficiency, not the answer for productivity. CLI FTW. 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtUuq.png

Comment: On one final word of advice, learn and LOVE CLI operators.

One of the tricks I've learned along my way is this lil rough and dirty combo punch.

`code` sudo nano /etc/psad/psad.conf & cd ~/Documents/ && touch echo "psad.conf-"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"` && cat /etc/psad/psad.conf >> "psad.conf-"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"` `code`

(Adjusting per file of course) That had saved my bacon so many times.